# The specified value "undefined" cannot be parsed, or is out of range

Tags: javascript, html, calculator, calculation, input-field

SO I am trying to make a POS web based app in the billing part I am trying to add the total column only that are added by the JavaScript but it doesn't adds up

HTML: -

```
            <table id="tbl">
              <thead>
                <th>Product Name</th>

                <th>Description</th>

                <th>Price</th>

                <th>Quantity</th>

                <th>Total</th>
              </thead>
            </table>
```

I have created a button that dose a couple of things other then this, it should show the summed amount in the input field but this JS doesn't shows the summed amount: -

```
let subTotal = document.getElementById("tbl").getElementsByTagName("td");

  let sum;

  for (let i = 0; i < subTotal.length; i++) {
    if (subTotal[i].id == "lstTtl") {
      sum += isNaN(subTotal[i].innerHTML) ? 0 : parseInt(subTotal[i].innerHTML);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("sTotal").value = sum;
```

Trying to get a calculated amount from a table that is added dynamically.

Comment: Are you getting any output at all? If so, what is it?

Comment: Also, did you try setting the innerHTML of sTotal?

Comment: I am not getting any output the field remains empty and yes I tried it setting with innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

`isNaN` will always return true for anything that isn't a number, which `subTotal[i].innerHTML` never is, therefore sum will always be +0.

```
if (subTotal[i].id == "lstTtl") {
  const num = parseInt(subTotal[i].innerHTML);
  if(!isNaN(num) {
    sum += num;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but it's still udefined.

Comment: @ZainJaved Without your full code (HTML + JS) in a snippet, it's hard to investigate further.